# After installer Instagram-scraper with pip3, when I try to run it, it says there's no such command

Tags: python3, pip

I used

pip3 install instagram-scraper

to install instagram scraper and then I used

pip3 list

and I can see Instagram-scraper installed but if I try to check which version,
when I type

instagram-scraper --version

it says it can't find a command called "instagram-scraper"

Comment: Try `~/.local/bin/instagram-scraper --version`. Pip3, when run without `sudo`, is not allowed to install in a system-wide directory such as `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thank you, It's worked.

Comment: ^ when this works, you can/should add this folder to your user's PATH, e.g. by appending a line `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin` to your `~/.profile` file if there isn't such a line already. Modern Ubuntu versions enable this conditionally, so you might just have to log out and back in to reload it if the directory just got created.

Answer (score 0):

When `pip` runs as normal user (or with `--user`, depending on version) it stores executables by default in your `~/.local/bin` folder. This location might not be in your `$PATH` variable yet.

Check if you can run the command as

```
~/.local/bin/instagram-scraper --version
```

If this works, you should make sure this folder is added to your user's `$PATH`:

Check your `~/.profile` file. On modern Ubuntu versions, it should already conditionally add this location to `$PATH` if it exists when you log in, using a snippet looking like this:

```bsh
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

If you don't find such a block in your `~/.profile` script, append it to the file and save.

Either way, as this is only checked when you log in, you have to log out and back in now if you just added the snippet or if the directory was just created during this session.

After that, you should see `/home/USERNAME/.local/bin` as part of the output of `echo "$PATH"`, and `instagram-scraper --version` should work directly without specifying a directory.